# search with enter key input value

Tags: jquery, search, enter

https://memoshome.com/en/advanced-search/?property_identity=test%20keyword

this is my search result page. If I write something to the Pro ID input on this page and click the Search Button then the property id parameter changes. But if I press enter, the old parameter comes up. I used the following code for the enter key to work. how can i solve this?

```
$(document).on('keyup keypress keydown', ".ere-search-content input", function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $('.ere-advanced-search-btn').trigger("click");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Seems like it works on your page, I hit enter and the search starts...

Comment: Change the location that says 123456 on this page and press the enter key on the keyboard again. 123456 will come again. https://memoshome.com/en/advanced-search/?status=for-sale&property_identity=123456

Comment: I'd try submitting a form programmatically instead of faking a button click (`form.submit()`)

Comment: Well, what would you expect? it has `value="123456"` on page load - :D

Comment: thanks entio. this is too complicated for me.)